# Assembly language numbers: is MOV AX,1 ASCII or integer

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, masm, emu8086

What is difference between

```
num db 1
mov ax,1
```

And `mov ax, num`

Is it ASCII or integer when `mov ax,1` is executed?

I mean, the number is not inserted from keyboard, it is predefined, may it ask to convert it to integer? Is it ASCII?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII is type of encoding, i.e. how you should interpret certain numeric value, like "33 is exclamation"...

But the CPU doesn't know ASCII, `mov al,33` just sets `al` register to bit pattern `00100001`, and when some other code will use that value as ASCII character (like drawing some glyph from provided font graphics to the display), it will emerge as "exclamation mark".

On the CPU level it's just number `33`. `mov al,'!'` and `mov al,33` and `mov al,21h` will all produce binary identical machine instruction (loading that bit pattern 00100001 into register `al`), there's no difference for CPU. All difference is just "formatting sugar" of source (making it easier for programmer to understand what was original intent of source, if the number 33 in `al` is expected to be used as ASCII character (`mov al,'!'`), or as numeric value in some calculation (`mov al,33`)).

To enter (in source) ASCII character value use the single-quote like `mov ax,'1'`, that will assemble as `mov ax,49` (in emu8086, MASM, and almost all of the other x86 assemblers, but it's feature of the assembler, you may run into assemblers which do not understand this "character" syntax, and then you will have to use something like `mov ax,49` to get the same result).

---

`mov ax,num` will set `al` (bottom 8 bits of `ax`) to 1, and `ah` (upper 8 bits of `ax`) to some undefined value (you do `db 1`, but then you read word, so to make sure you load word value 1, you should define two bytes at address `num`, like `num: db 1, 0` or easier to read `num: dw 1` (again both variants produce identical machine code for CPU, the difference is only in source code).

If you would define `num: dw 1`, then after executing `mov ax,1` vs `mov ax,num` the result is identical, in both cases the `ax` will contain value 1. But in the first variant the value `1` is encoded inside the instruction itself (`B80100` is machine code for `mov ax,1` for 8086 CPU). And in the second variant (in Intel syntax it is `mov ax,[num]`, which I strongly recommend to use even with emu8086 or MASM, to make the memory access visible when reading source code) does read two bytes from memory (additionally to the three bytes of the instruction opcode, which was read+decoded before).

So the `mov ax,1` will be probably more performant in most of the scenarios, but `mov ax,[num]` is more flexible (something can modify the value in memory, then the result will be no more `1`, but that new modified value). (it's **possible** to self-modify also the instruction `mov ax,1` to change the value encoded in machine code, but that option is generally frown upon, because it makes the source usually harder to understand, and it has severe performance and security implications on modern x86 machines, so this practice has been abandoned)

Answer (score 3):

`num db 1`, define 1 byte in memory and initialize it to integer value 1.

`Mov ax,1` is an immediate addressing mode which transfers (copy) integer 1 to ax register. Whereas `Mov ax, num` is a Register direct addressing mode which transfers value contains in `num` to `ax` register.

---

For ASCII you use the following instruction:

`num db '1'`; define 1 byte and initialize '1' ASCII value to memory

`Mov ax,'1'`

`Mov ax,num`
; '1' has been converted to its equivalent ASCII (integer 49) code by assembler.

Comment: `mov ax, num` uses direct addressing. Register indirect addressing would be something like `mov ax, [bx]`.

Comment: @SusheelDwivedi: You can and should [edit] your answer to fix mistakes.

Comment: now i fix my mistake indirect addressing mode to direct addressing mode thanks Michael :)

Comment: There's no register involved in the addressing mode.  It's a `[disp16]` with no base, just an absolute address.